# javax.mail working on emaulator but not on android real mobile device

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

In android activity, i am sending email by using Gmail SMTP and javax.mail class.

It works fine on Emulator but it is not working on my android mobile device.

Here is my code

```
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);


        System.out.println("SSLEmail Start");
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com"); //SMTP Host
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); //TLS Port
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); //enable authentication
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); //enable STARTTLS

        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
            //override the getPasswordAuthentication method
            protected javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication(fromEmail, password);
            }
        }; 

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, auth);
```

Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: Please elaborate on "doesn't work".  What does the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show?  Also, you'll want to fix these [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).  And make sure you're using the official [JavaMail for Android](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#JavaMail_for_Android).

Comment: It is resolved by adding these dependencies in build.gradle,

dependencies {
     compile 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.5.5'
     compile 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.5.5'
 }

because, Android does not provide a Java Compatible runtime and so can't run the standard JavaMail distribution. Instead, a special version of JavaMail is available for Android.